# How do I move inside of a dynamic object in javascript using just the keys that are saved in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, javascript-objects

Here is my example. I have an object in Javascript that is dynamically changed.
And I want in this case the value of the property "inside" and I know that the value is in the place `a[something][anotherthing][inside]`. Because I saved the position in an array `["a","somethig", "anotherthing"]`. my question is How do I move to that position using the keys that are in the array?. Already tried to concat the elements and the final result is something like this `myObject[a][somthing][anotherthing]` but the problem is that it returns 'undefined' because it's a string. Is there any chance to convert it to object or some way to get that position in the object?

```
var myarray = ['a', 'something', 'anotherthing'];
myObject = {
  a: {
    something: {
      anotherthing: {
        inside: 10
      }
    }
  },
  b: {
    insideb: {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to reduce the array to a single value. You will pass in `myObject` as the starting point (second parameter), then use this basic callback (first parameter):

```
(obj, itm) => obj[itm]
```

When you put it all together, it will look like this:

```js
var myarray = ['a', 'something', 'anotherthing'];

myObject = {
  a: {
    something: {
      anotherthing: {
        inside: 10
      }
    }
  },
  b: {
    insideb: {

    }
  }
}

let result = myarray.reduce((obj, itm) => obj[itm], myObject)

console.log(result)
console.log(result.inside)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact location of the value: `myObject['a']['somthing']['anotherthing']` will give you the value.

If you need to step through the object dynamically, you can use: `Object.keys(myObject).forEach(key => myObject[key]);` to get the top level keys.

Comment: I know the exact location of the value but the problem is that is stored in an array and when I try make a loop on it, it returns a string , how do I concat the string with an object? or should I change the way of how store the location?. Thanks

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you correctly, the array with keys are generated dynamically and you need to use that to get to the value in the object? If that is the case, the easiest would be: `let result = myObject[myarray[0]][myarray[1]][myarray[2]]['inside']`